# How to generate an IBM Cloud token from an API Key

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-kubernetes, ibm-cloud-iam

I have generated an API key for IBM Cloud, how do I programmatically generate a token from the API key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a curl request to do that.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://iam.cloud.ibm.com/identity/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Yng6Yng=' \
--data-urlencode 'apikey=xxx' \
--data-urlencode 'response_type=cloud_iam' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ibm:params:oauth:grant-type:apikey'
```

Replace `xxx` with your API key.

The basic authorization is base64 encoded with a username of `bx` and a password of `bx`.

The response looks like the following:

```
{
    "access_token": "bearer token",
    "refresh_token": "refresh token",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "expiration": 1581031424,
    "scope": "ibm openid"
}
```