# How to generate a kubeconfig for my kubernetes cluster in ibm cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

I am wondering how do I create a kube config file for my Kubernetes cluster programatically so I can use it with `kubectl` in IBM Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a Kube config file to use with `kubectl` you can do the following via curl to generate the file.

First you will need to get your bearer and refresh token.  There are a couple ways to do this.  If you have an API key you [can generate your tokens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60104518/3817025).

Once you have your tokens you can call the following API.

`POST https://containers.cloud.ibm.com/global/v1/clusters/clusterid/config`.

That will give you a zipped file with the kube config and relevant certificates.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://containers.cloud.ibm.com/global/v1/clusters/xxx/config' \
--header 'Authorization: mybearertoken' \
--header 'X-Auth-Refresh-Token: myrefreshtoken' >> kubeconfig.zip
```

Replace `mybearertoken` and `myrefreshtoken` with the correct values from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60104518/3817025).